# How to awk specific fields from python subprocess output

Tags: python-3.x, db2-luw

```
  Tablespace name                          = SYSCATSPACE

  Tablespace ID                            = 0

  Tablespace Type                          = Database managed space

  Tablespace Content Type                  = All permanent data. Regular table space.

  Tablespace Page size (bytes)             = 16384

  Tablespace Extent size (pages)           = 4

  Automatic Prefetch size enabled          = Yes

  Buffer pool ID currently in use          = 1

  Buffer pool ID next startup              = 1

  Using automatic storage                  = Yes

  Auto-resize enabled                      = Yes
```

How can I select the `tablespace name` if the `auto resize` tag is set to `yes`? (I need to do this to x amounts to tablespaces that are displayed with additonal information).

Comment: the awk command could achieve this easily but am trying to do it a pythonic way of selecting the tablespace name  if and only if that tablespace name has the autorize set to YES ....

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Answer (score 1):

What db2 command are you using to get this output ?

Instead of trying to parse the output,  you should select the tablespaces from db2 catalog sytem tables,  and filter your rows per your need..

```
SELECT MEMBER, TBSP_ID, TBSP_NAME FROM TABLE(MON_GET_TABLESPACE('',-2)) AS t  
   WHERE  TBSP_AUTO_RESIZE_ENABLED = 1
```

easier.

PS.  I don't know what you mean by doing it a **"pythonic"** way. python has no magic way, under the covers,  it has to ask DB2 for the information.  I am giving you the best way to retrieve the information you want, from db2 perspective..  regardless the language being used.